# Distance between formulas and text

Tags: overleaf

In the code below code, you can see that the distance between the formula and text is unusually large. Is it possible to reduce that distance?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,text={16.5cm,25.2cm},centering]{geometry}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % no longer needed
%\usepackage[english]{babel} % not actually needed

%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}% also loads amsmath
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{enumerate}  


\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{setspace}

% for mock text, not needed in a real document
\usepackage{lipsum}

% must be last almost all the times
\usepackage{hyperref}

\onehalfspacing
%\doublespacing

\newcommand{\isEquivTo}[1]{\underset{#1}{\sim}}

\newcommand{\RN}[1]{%
  \textup{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral#1}}%
}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newmdtheoremenv{theo}[theorem]{Theorem}
%\newmdtheoremenv{lem}[lemma]{Lemma}
%\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}

\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}

%\newcommand\smallO{%
 % \mathchoice
  %  {{\scriptstyle\mathcal{O}}}% \displaystyle
   % {{\scriptstyle\mathcal{O}}}% \textstyle
    %{{\scriptscriptstyle\mathcal{O}}}% \scriptstyle
    %{\scalebox{.7}%{$\scriptscriptstyle\mathcal{O}$}}%\scriptscriptstyle
  %}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

 This follows form the triangle inequality, since
\begin{equation*}
|\chi(x_1+x_2)-1|=|\chi(x_1)\chi(x_2)-\chi(x_1)\overline{\chi(x_1)}|=|\chi(x_2)-\overline{\chi(x_1)}|,
\end{equation*}
where.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example is far from minimal. Also, does the problem go away if you don't do the setup of interlinespace? Finally, it could be useful in this case to show an image of your output.

Comment: Does it help to load the `setspace` package with the option `nodisplayskipstretch`?

Comment: Any chance you can get away with not running `\onehalfspacing`?

Comment: @Mico, if I remove `\onehalfspacing` then it reduces the distance too much.

Comment: @Mico, can you explain how to load `setspace` with the mentioned option?

Comment: @RFZ - `\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}`.